# how to assign margin-right to dynamically generated chat boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have done some php and mysql stuff to generate dynamic chat boxes. everything is okay but if there is more then one chat box the problem occurs with alignment. two chat boxes doesn't align with inline-block. I want tyo make chat boxes inline-block but i don't how to do that i have tried many ways but still going through this irritated error please look at my code and tell me where  i am doing wrong

look at the current output it overlays each other i want to get it as image placed at right side:

[image: look at the current output it overlays each other i want to get it as image placed at right side]

```
<?
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('social_net', $con) or die('error in(application/view/chatting.php) at line 3');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="facivon.ico">

<title>Facebook like chat</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

.chat_box{
    position:fixed;
    right:20px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:250px;
}
.chat_body{
    background:white;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    padding:5px 0px;
}

.chat_head,.msg_head{
    background:#f39c12;
    color:white;
    padding:15px;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.msg_box{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-5px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    width:250px;
    background:white;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.msg_head{
    background:#3498db;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}

.msg_body{
    background:white;
    height:200px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:15px;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.msg_input{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    resize:none;
}

.close{
    float:right;
    margin:-15px;
    border-radius:0px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding:15px;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:rgba(71, 62, 48, 0.63) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.minimize{
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-right:5px;

}

.user{
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 30px;
}
.user:hover{
    background:#f8f8f8;
    cursor:pointer;

}
.user-0{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:#535a56;
    height:7px;
    width:7px;
    left:10px;
    top:18px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.user-1{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:#2ecc71;
    height:7px;
    width:7px;
    left:10px;
    top:18px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.msg_a{
    position:relative;
    background:#FDE4CE;
    padding:10px;
    min-height:10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.msg_a:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-color: transparent #FDE4CE transparent transparent;
    left:-20px;
    top:7px;
}


.msg_b{
    background:#EEF2E7;
    padding:10px;
    min-height:15px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.msg_b:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #EEF2E7;
    right:-20px;
    top:7px;
}
#finfrndslink
{
    display:block;
    padding:.6em;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:94%;
    margin-top: 10em;
    background: rgb(54, 42, 42) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
    </style>
       <script src="<?=base_url().'assets/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'?>"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.msg_box').hide();
        $('.chat_head').click(function(){
            $('.chat_body').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?
    $user_name = $this->session->userdata('user');
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$user_name'";
    $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
    $u_id = $row1['u_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM friends T1 JOIN users T2 ON T1.frnd_id=T2.u_id WHERE T1.u_id='$u_id' && T1.status='confirm'";
    $query3 = mysql_query($sql);
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
  ?>
  <div class="chat_box">
    <div class="chat_head">Chat</div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="chat_body">  
    <?
    if($count!=0)
    {
        $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            ?>
                <div class="user" id="u<?=$i?>" style="text-transform:capitalize"><span class="user-<?=$row['logged_in'];?>"></span><?=$row['f_name'].' '.$row['l_name']?></div>
            <?
            $i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <a href='<?=base_url()?>find_friends' id='finfrndslink'>Find Friends</a>
        <?
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?
    $i=1;
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3))
        {
            ?>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#mh<?=$i?>').click(function(){
                        $('#mw<?=$i?>').slideToggle('slow');
                    });

                    $('#cl<?=$i?>').click(function(){
                        $('#mb<?=$i?>').hide();
                    });

                    $('#u<?=$i?>').click(function(){
                        $('#mw<?=$i?>').show();
                        $('#mb<?=$i?>').show();
                    });

                    $('#ti<?=$i?>').keypress(
                    function(e){
                        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var msg = $(this).val();
                            $(this).val('');
                            if(msg!='')
                            $('<div class="msg_b">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('#msg_push<?=$i?>');
                            $('#msg_body<?=$i?>').scrollTop($('#msg_body<?=$i?>')[0].scrollHeight);
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>
                <div class="msg_box" id="mb<?=$i?>" style="right:290px">
                    <div class="msg_head" id="mh<?=$i?>">
                    <font style="text-transform:capitalize"><?=$row1['f_name'].' '.$row1['l_name']?></font>
                    <div class="close" id="cl<?=$i?>" title="Close">x</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="msg_wrap" id="mw<?=$i?>">
                        <div class="msg_body" id="msg_body<?=$i?>">
                            <div class="msg_a">This is from A   </div>
                            <div class="msg_b">This is from B, and its amazingly kool nah... i know it even i liked it :)</div>
                            <div class="msg_a">Wow, Thats great to hear from you man </div> 
                            <div class="msg_push" id="msg_push<?=$i?>"></div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" id="ti<?=$i?>" placeholder="write your message here" rows="2"></textarea></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use class selector instead of id selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign CSS properties with jQuery. One example will be `$(selector).css("margin-right", "20px")`.

Comment: i have tried that way but it doesn't works for me because selectors are also dynamic @Nicholas

Comment: What did you put for the selector? What about calling the function right after your so-called "dynamic" chat boxes are created?

Comment: as you can see in the code above the ID selectors are created using while loop for each chat box so that's why every time chat boxes has different id's @Nicholas

Comment: What about assigning the same class name to each and every of the chat boxes with `$(selector).addClass("boxClass")` so you can do `$(".boxClass").css("margin-right", "20px")`?

Comment: it doesn't works because the position of div is fixed